# Sorting words in order of frequency? (least to greatest)

Tags: java, sorting

does any one have any idea how to sort a list of words in the order of their frequency (least to greatest) using the built in `collection.sort` and a `comparator<string>` interface?

I already have a method that gets the count of a certain word in the text file. Now, I just need to create a method that compares the counts of each word and then puts them in a list sorted by the least frequency to the greatest.

Any ideas and tips would be very much appreciated. I'm having trouble getting started on this particular method.

```
public class Parser implements Comparator<String> {

    public Map<String, Integer> wordCount;

    void parse(String filename) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(filename);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);

        //mapping of string -> integer (word -> frequency)
        Map<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

        //iterates through each word in the text file
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
            String word = scanner.next();
            if (scanner.next()==null) {
                wordCount.put(word, 1);
            }
            else {
                wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word) + 1);;
                }
            }
            scanner.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ");
            scanner.next().toLowerCase();
        }

    public int getCount(String word) {
        return wordCount.get(word);
    }

    public int compare(String w1, String w2) {
        return getCount(w1) - getCount(w2);
    } 

        //this method should return a list of words in order of frequency from least to   greatest
    public List<String> getWordsInOrderOfFrequency() {
        List<Integer> wordsByCount = new ArrayList<Integer>(wordCount.values());
        //this part is unfinished.. the part i'm having trouble sorting the word frequencies
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();


    }
}
```

Comment: Sure, create a class that holds a String (for the word), and an int (for the count), and make it implement `Comparable<Yourclass>` and then in the compareTo(...) method, compare based on the int values.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I actually mapped the list of words from a string to an integer to keep the count of each frequency. I'm not sure how to sort the words by frequency using the map property and collections.sort method

Comment: Write some code and post it.  We'll go over it.

Comment: hey, i added my code. I'm not looking for code to copy, but suggestions to improve and finish the frequency method. Thanks!

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(justTheWords, this)`

Comment: Where you have your comment `//this part is unfinished`, just do: `List<String> justWords = new ArrayList<String>(wordCount.keySet()); List<String> result = Collections.sort(justWords, this);`...

Comment: ^^Torious, that didn't seem to work when I tried it. Thanks for the help though

Comment: The idea was that `sort` will call `this.compare()` during sorting, to compare 2 `String`s, which are then compared by first looking up the count in `this` (the `Parser` instance). That's assuming `parse` was called first. I figured that was the intent of the original code, looking at the `compare` method. Did I miss something?

Comment: @Torious: Oh, I'm sorry. Now I understand how it works (and deleted my comments). I didn't realize how the Comparator would work on the Map, while being declared on <String>, not <String, Int>. Now it is so obvious! :)

Answer (score 7):

First of all your usage of `scanner.next()` seems incorrect. `next()` will return the next word and move onto next one every time you call it, therefore the following code:

```
if(scanner.next() == null){ ... }
```

and also

```
scanner.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ");
scanner.next().toLowerCase();
```

will consume and then just throw away words. What you probably want to do is:

```
String word = scanner.next().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]"," ").toLowerCase();
```

at the beginning of your `while` loop, so that the changes to your word are saved in the `word` variable, and not just thrown away.

Secondly, the usage of the `wordCount` map is slightly broken. What you want to do is to check if the `word` is already in the map to decide what word count to set. To do this, instead of checking for `scanner.next() == null` you should look in the map, for example:

```
if(!wordCount.containsKey(word)){
  //no count registered for the word yet
  wordCount.put(word, 1);
}else{
  wordCount.put(word, wordCount.get(word) + 1);
}
```

alternatively you can do this:

```
Integer count = wordCount.get(word);
if(count == null){
  //no count registered for the word yet
  wordCount.put(word, 1);
}else{
  wordCount.put(word, count+1);
}
```

I would prefer this approach, because it's a bit cleaner, and does only one map look-up per word, whereas the first approach sometimes does two look-ups.

Now, to get a list of words in descending order of frequencies, you can convert your map to a list first, then apply `Collections.sort()` as was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java). Below is a simplified version suited to your needs:

```
static List<String> getWordInDescendingFreqOrder(Map<String, Integer> wordCount) {

    // Convert map to list of <String,Integer> entries
    List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> list = 
        new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(wordCount.entrySet());

    // Sort list by integer values
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<String, Integer> o2) {
            // compare o2 to o1, instead of o1 to o2, to get descending freq. order
            return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });

    // Populate the result into a list
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : list) {
        result.add(entry.getKey());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Edit:**
Changed the comparison function as suggested by @dragon66. Thanks.

Comment: Why not return (o2.getValue()).compareTo(o1.getValue()) instead of *-1

Comment: thanks. it helps a lot. but for some reason now "Parser" in "Public class Parser implements Comparator<String>" is underlined in red telling me that it needs to inherit the abstract method? I'm confused why it's doing this.

Comment: Is the `int compare(String w1, String w2)` method still there? If you are using Jdk6 you may also have to prefix your method with `@Override` annotation, otherwise it will complain. Also, you can always put the `getWordInDescendingFreqOrder()` method into another class and reference it from your class.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare and extract ideas from the following:

```
public class FrequencyCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // read in the words as an array
        String s = StdIn.readAll();
        // s = s.toLowerCase();
        // s = s.replaceAll("[\",!.:;?()']", "");
        String[] words = s.split("\\s+");

        // sort the words
        Merge.sort(words);

        // tabulate frequencies of each word
        Counter[] zipf = new Counter[words.length];
        int M = 0;                                        // number of distinct words
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0 || !words[i].equals(words[i-1]))   // short-circuiting OR
                zipf[M++] = new Counter(words[i], words.length);
            zipf[M-1].increment();
        }

        // sort by frequency and print
        Merge.sort(zipf, 0, M);                           // sorting a subarray
        for (int j = M-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            StdOut.println(zipf[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution, close to your original posting with corrections and the sorting as suggested by Torious in the comments:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Parser implements Comparator <String> {

    public Map<String, Integer> wordCount;

    void parse ()
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        // don't redeclare it here - your attribute wordCount will else be shadowed
        wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer> ();

        //iterates through each word in the text file
        while (scanner.hasNext ()) {
            String word = scanner.next ();
            // operate on the word, not on next and next of next word from Scanner
            word = word.replaceAll (" [^A-Za-z0-9]", " ");
            word = word.toLowerCase ();
            // look into your map:
            if (! wordCount.containsKey (word))
                wordCount.put (word, 1);
            else
                wordCount.put (word, wordCount.get (word) + 1);;
        }
    }

    public int getCount (String word) {
        return wordCount.get (word);
    }

    public int compare (String w1, String w2) {
        return getCount (w1) - getCount (w2);
    }

    public List<String> getWordsInOrderOfFrequency () {
        List<String> justWords = new ArrayList<String> (wordCount.keySet());
        Collections.sort (justWords, this);
        return justWords; 
    }

    public static void main (String args []) {
        Parser p = new Parser ();
        p.parse ();
        List<String> ls = p.getWordsInOrderOfFrequency ();
        for (String s: ls) 
            System.out.println (s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

rodions Solution is a kind of a Generics hell, but I don't have it simpler - just different.

In the End, his solution is shorter and better.

At the first looks, it seems that a TreeMap might be appropriate, but it sorts by Key, and is of no help for sorting by value, and we can't switch key-value, because we look it up by the key.

So the next idea is to generate a HashMap, and use Collections.sort, but it doesn't take a Map, just Lists for sorting. From a Map, there is entrySet, which produces another Collection, which is a Set, and not a List. That was the point where I took another direction:

I implemented an Iterator: I iterate over the entrySet, and only return Keys, where the value is 1. If the value is 2, I buffer them for later use. If the Iterator is exhausted, I look into the buffer, and if it isn't empty, I use the iterator of the buffer in future, increment the minimum value I look for, and create a new Buffer.

The advantage of an Iterator/Iterable pair is, that the values can be obtained by the simplified for-loop.

```
import java.util.*;

// a short little declaration :) 
public class WordFreq implements Iterator <Map.Entry <String, Integer>>, Iterable <Map.Entry <String, Integer>>
{
    private Map <String, Integer> counter;
    private Iterator <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> it;
    private Set <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> buf;
    private int maxCount = 1; 

    public Iterator <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> iterator () {
        return this;
    }

    // The iterator interface expects a "remove ()" - nobody knows why
    public void remove ()
    {
        if (hasNext ())
            next ();
    } 

    public boolean hasNext ()
    {
        return it.hasNext () || ! buf.isEmpty ();
    }

    public Map.Entry <String, Integer> next ()
    {
        while (it.hasNext ()) {
            Map.Entry <String, Integer> mesi = it.next ();
            if (mesi.getValue () == maxCount)
                return mesi;
            else
                buf.add (mesi);
        }
        if (buf.isEmpty ())
            return null;
        ++maxCount;
        it = buf.iterator (); 
        buf = new HashSet <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> ();     
        return next ();
    } 

    public WordFreq ()
    {
        it = fill ();
        buf = new HashSet <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> ();
        // The "this" here has to be an Iterable to make the foreach work
        for (Map.Entry <String, Integer> mesi : this)
        {
            System.out.println (mesi.getValue () + ":\t" + mesi.getKey ());
        }
    }

    public Iterator <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> fill ()
    {
        counter = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        while (sc.hasNext ())
        {
            push (sc.next ());
        }
        Set <Map.Entry <String, Integer>> set = counter.entrySet ();
        return set.iterator ();
    }

    public void push (String word)
    {
        Integer i = counter.get (word);
        int n = 1 + ((i != null) ? i : 0); 
        counter.put (word, n);
    }

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        new WordFreq ();
    }
}
```

Since my solution reads from stdin, you invoke it with:

```
cat WordFreq.java | java WordFreq
```