# Sort a list by frequency of strings in it

Tags: java

List is

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

list.add("apple");
list.add("ball");
list.add("apple");
list.add("cat");
list.add("ball");
```

Now I have to sort this list with frequency of the apple, ball, cat

I have to get output as:

```
apple
ball
cat
```

Comment: not understand you question....

Comment: Please share what you've tried and we'll be happy to help.  You might want to try google as well.  If I search for "_java sort list by frequency_" the first result brings me right to a great answer on this site.

Comment: Already answered in the same forum.   Refer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158793/sorting-words-in-order-of-frequency-least-to-greatest

Comment: *Hint:* use Google Guava's `MultiSet` which already counts the frequencies for you.

Comment: use collections.frequency() to count occuranses http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection, java.lang.Object) . the create a hash map han sort it according to value

Answer (score 2):

First, count the occurrence of string and then sort by using Map

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("apple");
list.add("ball");
list.add("apple");
list.add("cat");
list.add("ball");
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for (String s : list) {
    if (map.containsKey(s)) {
        map.put(s, map.get(s) + 1);
    } else {
        map.put(s, 1);
    }
}
ValueComparator<String, Integer> comparator = new ValueComparator<String, Integer> (map);
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new TreeMap<String, Integer> (comparator);
sortedMap.putAll(map);

List<String> sortedList = new ArrayList<String> (sortedMap.keySet());

System.out.println(sortedMap);
System.out.println(sortedList);

}

static class ValueComparator<K, V extends Comparable<V>> implements Comparator<K> {

Map<K, V> map;

public ValueComparator(Map<K, V> base) {
    this.map = base;
}

@Override
public int compare(K o1, K o2) {
     return map.get(o2).compareTo(map.get(o1));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a customized list containing a map that registers the frequency of an element in the list.

```
pulic class FrequencySortList<E> extend ArrayList<E> {

  private Map<E,Integer> frequency = new HashMap<E,Integer>();


  .....




}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
List list = new ArrayList();
         list.add("apple");
         list.add("ball");
         list.add("apple");
         list.add("cat");
         list.add("ball");

         // sort the list
         Collections.sort(list);
```

Here your list contains:

```
apple
apple
ball
ball
cat
         List list2 = new  ArrayList();

         for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
         {
             if(!list2.contains(list.get(i)))
             {
                 list2.add(list.get(i));
             }

         }
         for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++)
         {

             System.out.println(list2.get(i));
         }
```

list2 will  print:

```
apple
ball
cat
```

or you can do the same thing with using this single line as jahroy mentioned in comment

```
List list2 = new ArrayList<String>(new TreeSet<String>(list));
```

Comment: The OP would like to sort the list by the number of occurrences of each element.  This will generate a list of unique elements sorted alphabetically.  Also, you could achieve the same effect of the above code like this: `Set<String> s = new TreeSet<String>(list);`, which will create a sorted collection of unique elements.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to make simple class as your model :

```
public class Thing {

        String name;
        int total;

        public Thing(String name){
            this.name=name;
            total=1;
        }

       //setter and getter
    }
```

then you need to calculate how many frequency of that thing appears :

```
List list = new ArrayList();
list.add("apple");
list.add("ball");
list.add("apple");
list.add("cat");
list.add("ball");
System.out.println(list.size());
List list2 = new ArrayList();
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
    Thing thing= new Thing(list.get(i).toString());
    if(list2.size()<1){
        list2.add(thing);
    }else {
        boolean insert=true;
        int x=0;
        for(int j=0;j<list2.size();j++){
            Thing toCompare=(Thing)list2.get(j);
            if(toCompare.getName().equals(thing.getName())){
                insert=false;
                x=j;
                thing.setTotal(thing.getTotal()+1);
                break;
            }
        }
        if(insert==true){
            list2.add(thing);
        }else{
            list2.set(x, thing);
        }
    }
}

for(int i=0;i<list2.size();i++){
    Thing thing=(Thing)list2.get(i);
    System.out.println(thing.getName()+" : "+thing.getTotal());
}
```